# Upper table visibility in select with multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT b.user_id, b.active FROM users b
WHERE b.followers_count != (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM (SELECT u.user_id
        FROM user_follow uf,users u,user_follow_request ufr
        WHERE
        uf.following_id = b.user_id AND
        uf.following_id = ufr.friend_id AND
        ufr.status = 'approved' AND
        ufr.user_id = u.user_id AND u.user_id != b.user_id AND u.active != 0
        GROUP BY u.user_id) a) 
 AND b.active = -1 limit 5;
```

It has to select all the `user_id`'s from `users` that have different `followers_count` in the column from the one being calculated by sql.

But the problem is that I'm receiving error message

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'b.user_id' in 'on clause'
```

What I'm doing wrong? Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Try to use original name ie., users instead of b.

Comment: still no luck.Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Use explicit join syntax throughout. Don't mix and match implicit (comma) join syntax and explicit JOIN syntax. The order in which tables are joined becomes (in a sense) unpredictable. That said, your problem is more complicated and can't easily be solved without seeing the actual tables.

Comment: It would be nice to provide a data example and a result you expect from it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `uf.user_id = b.user_id` instead of `uf.following_id = b.user_id`? Anyway, what `user_follow` table is for?

Agree to Strawberry, you'd better use explicit joins. They are much easier to read and understand. Here is what you may have mentioned (note that `user_follow` table is not used at all):

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.followers_count, IF(ISNULL(uafc.actual_fc),0,uafc.actual_fc) AS afc
  FROM users AS u
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT u.user_id AS user_id, COUNT(*) AS actual_fc
        FROM users AS u
          JOIN user_follow_request AS ufr
            ON ufr.friend_id = u.user_id
          JOIN users AS fu
            ON fu.user_id = ufr.user_id
        WHERE ufr.user_id != u.user_id
          AND ufr.status = 'approved'
          AND fu.active != 0
        GROUP BY u.user_id, u.followers_count
      ) AS uafc
      ON uafc.user_id = u.user_id
  WHERE u.followers_count != IF(ISNULL(uafc.actual_fc),0,uafc.actual_fc)
;
```

There may be some nicer solution for NULL workaround.

See it on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71f6c/3

Comment: This query doesn't work, doesn't return what it must user_follow is the table used for followers/following relationships, we have to  use it query, regarding explicit joins agree totally.

Comment: It would be nice to see tables structures and data example.